# Cocoapods push to private repo fails validation with unclear error - xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am trying to update a rather old cocoapod we use at my current employer. The cocoapod was in a GitHub repo that we removed and we are trying to move it to the new repo. I have updated the `podspec` as follows:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

  s.name         = "BBCommon"
  s.version      = "2.5.6"

  s.summary      = "REDACTED"

  s.description  = <<-DESC
                   REDACTED
                   DESC

  s.homepage     = "http://bodybuilding.com"
  s.license = { :type => 'REDACTED', :text => <<-LICENSE
                   REDACTED
                 LICENSE
              }
  s.author             = { "REDACTED" }
  s.platform = :ios
  s.ios.deployment_target = "13.0"
  s.source       = { :git => "git@REDACTED", :tag => s.version }
  s.source_files  = "BBCommon/BBCommon/Public/**/*.{h,m}", "BBCommon/BBCommon/Private/BBCommonLog.h"
  s.swift_version = '4.0'
  s.ios.exclude_files = "BBCommon/BBCommon/Public/Google/*.{h,m}"
  s.public_header_files = "BBCommon/BBCommon/Public/**/*.h"
  s.requires_arc = true
  s.ios.frameworks = 'UIKit', 'SystemConfiguration', 'Foundation'
  s.libraries = 'sqlite3', 'xml2'

  s.dependency "AFNetworking"
  s.dependency "Realm", "~> 0.90"
  s.dependency "REDACTED"
  s.dependency "REDACTED"
  s.dependency "REDACTED", "= 3.6.1"
  s.dependency "UICKeyChainStore"
  s.dependency "XMLDictionary", "~> 1.4"
  s.dependency "SDWebImage", "~> 3.7"

  s.subspec 'no-arc' do |sp|
    sp.source_files = "BBCommon/BBCommon/Public/Google/*.{h,m}"
    sp.requires_arc = false
  end

end
```

when I attempt `pod repo push {privatereponame} BBCommon.podspec --allow-warnings --verbose` I get the following output at the end of the very very long `--verbose` option:

```
 -> BBCommon (2.5.6)
    - WARN  | source: Git SSH URLs will NOT work for people behind firewalls configured to only allow HTTP, therefore HTTPS is preferred.
    - WARN  | url: There was a problem validating the URL http://bodybuilding.com.
    - ERROR | [BBCommon/no-arc] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code.
    - NOTE  | [BBCommon/no-arc] xcodebuild:  note: Using new build system
    - NOTE  | [BBCommon/no-arc] xcodebuild:  note: Building targets in parallel
    - NOTE  | [BBCommon/no-arc] xcodebuild:  note: Using codesigning identity override: -
    - NOTE  | [BBCommon/no-arc] xcodebuild:  note: Planning build
    - NOTE  | [BBCommon/no-arc] xcodebuild:  note: Constructing build description
    - NOTE  | [BBCommon/no-arc] xcodebuild:  <module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
    - NOTE  | [BBCommon/no-arc] xcodebuild:  Target Support Files/BBStoreClient/BBStoreClient-umbrella.h:14:9: note: in file included from Target Support Files/BBStoreClient/BBStoreClient-umbrella.h:14:
    - NOTE  | [BBCommon/no-arc] xcodebuild:  BBStoreClient/BBStoreClient/BBStoreClient/Public/BBStoreClient.h:28:9: note: in file included from BBStoreClient/BBStoreClient/BBStoreClient/Public/BBStoreClient.h:28:
    - NOTE  | [BBCommon/no-arc] xcodebuild:  BBStoreClient/BBStoreClient/BBStoreClient/Public/Entities/Profile/BBStoreCountry.h:7:9: note: in file included from BBStoreClient/BBStoreClient/BBStoreClient/Public/Entities/Profile/BBStoreCountry.h:7:
    - NOTE  | [BBCommon/no-arc] xcodebuild:  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    - NOTE  | [BBCommon/no-arc] xcodebuild:  warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'UICKeyChainStore' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [BBCommon/no-arc] xcodebuild:  warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'RequestUtils' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [BBCommon/no-arc] xcodebuild:  warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'SDWebImage' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [BBCommon/no-arc] xcodebuild:  warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'XMLDictionary' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [BBCommon/no-arc] xcodebuild:  warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'Realm' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [BBCommon/no-arc] xcodebuild:  warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'CSURITemplate' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [BBCommon/no-arc] xcodebuild:  warning: Skipping code signing because the target does not have an Info.plist file and one is not being generated automatically. (in target 'App' from project 'App')

[!] The `BBCommon.podspec` specification does not validate.

/Users/nate.birkholz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/push.rb:150:in `block in validate_podspec_files'
/Users/nate.birkholz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/push.rb:135:in `each'
/Users/nate.birkholz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/push.rb:135:in `validate_podspec_files'
/Users/nate.birkholz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/push.rb:76:in `run'
/Users/nate.birkholz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Users/nate.birkholz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Users/nate.birkholz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/nate.birkholz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/Users/nate.birkholz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

The library's `xcworkspace` builds fine in Xcode. `pod repo update` and `pod install` work fine. Latest version of cocoapods installed. Same results no matter what version of Ruby I use. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Hey Nate, I'm having the same issue and have some of the same lines in my output from the command (the linker failing, the simulator deployment versions not being compatible). Did you figure out a way around this?

Comment: had you fixed this issue? if yes than can you please guide me how to do treat with this error.

Comment: @NaeemHussain I’ afraid I don’t even recall if I fixed it by this point., sadly. Best wishes, sorry I cannot help.